# Chart.js via Visual Code is not displaying graph

Tags: javascript, html, graph, frontend

How can I display the script.js graph on this Covid-19 dashboard? For mine, it only shows the words. I have tried several attempts to let the script.js display the graph on the web, which includes placing `<link rel>` in the header instead of the body.

What possible reasons might lead to this problem?

**index.html file**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
            <title>Malaysia COVID-19 for March 2020</title>
            <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"> </script>
            <link rel = "stylesheet" typr = "text/css" href = "style.css">
            
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class = "wrapper">
                <h1>Malaysia COVID-19 Cases</h1>
                <h2>A simple line chart using Chart.js</h2>
    
                <canvas id = "mychart" width = "1600" heights = "900"></canvas>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**script.js file**

```
//For drawing the lines
var confirmed = [566, 673, 790, 900, 1030, 1183, 1306, 1518, 1624, 1796, 2031];
var recovered = [42, 49, 60, 75, 87, 114, 139, 183, 199, 215];
var death = [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 10, 14, 16, 20, 23];

var ctx = document.getElementById("mychart");

var mychart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type : 'line',
    data : {
        labels : day, 
        datasets: [
            {
                data: confirmed,
                label : "Confirmed Cases",
                borderColor: "#4933FF",
                fill: false
            },
            {
                data: recovered,
                label : "Recovered Cases",
                borderColor: "#00FF0C",
                fill: false
            },
            {
                data: death,
                label : "Death Cases",
                borderColor: "#00FF0C",
                fill: false
            }
        ]
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem. It's not related with the placement of the script tag, but to **remove the min** from the chart.min.js.Like this :

```
<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>
```

Then it will display the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your script after the CDN, otherwise the object Chart is not yet defined.

```
 <script src="cdn/chart.js"></script>
 <script>Your stuff</script>
```

Scripts should be at the end of body and you can use the console in the developer tools to have information about errors.

Comment: It something like this?
```
 <script src="cdn/chart.js"></script>
 <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```
Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: Cause when I typed that the graph still doesn't show up

Comment: No you need to use first the script tag with the source to chart.js then you can use the script tag with your code.